# Why was Officer Deville guarding the road during the opening?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-encounter

In [The Encounter](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1663680/) (a movie I can't really recommend, due to the low quality acting and predictable story), Officer Deville is found guarding a road that has been closed due to poor weather conditions, forcing three vehicles to turn back to the Last Chance Diner, where the story unfolds between the occupants of the vehicles.

At the end of the film, Deville comes to the diner and informs everyone that the road has been re-opened, and that it's perfectly safe.  The cafe owner, Jesus, says Deville is lying, but one of the diner customers chooses to trust Deville, leading to his predictable demise.

My question is:  Why was Deville guarding the road in the first place?  If he wants to deceive and harm the travelers, as is clearly the case, why was satan, posing as an officer, guarding the road?

It's quite possible this was simply another oversight, but the movie is clearly an attempt at allegory.  Was there something more meaningful going on here, that I didn't catch?

Answer (score 1):

A possible answer though I have nothing to back this up is that the Devil is a tempter. If it's an allegory then the people would be souls and the cafe would stand for their last chance for redemption. In order to obtain the souls the Devil would need to actually trick them into leaving after they are offered a chance to save themselves.

An argument could also be made that taking one soul from Jesus gives him more satisfaction than taking the five souls would have.

Answer (score -3):

Satan has free will but don't forget that the Devil is controlled by God. He's like a dog on a leash. The Bible calls him a toothless lion all he can do is go after the weary and try to tempt or frighten them.  Remember how he got *permission* from God to go after Job.

My guess is God uses him to test people's faith. But of course, Satan wants more than that.

Jesus closed the road to keep the strangers from getting into a car accident which would've killed them.